# Create mathematical expression mfc (VS6)

Tags: math, mfc

I need to write some mathematical expressions (like a matrix and mathematical variables...) into my GUI.

The MFC static control is very limited on this issue. Especially for the math. symbols.

Is there any control or other way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK all I did now is a bit dirty, but I put everything with static controls together and changed the font to Symbol from microsoft to get the greek letters.

You maybe need to resize and move some of the controls but then everythings seems to work.

So all in all kinda dirty.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out MFC Grid Control: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is only one good math editor, see http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathplayer/ . It's not so much a ready-to-use control though, it may or may not work for your application.

Consider allowing TeX-style equations in your application. Again, depending on your audience, this may or may not be an option.

Comment: well I need to display tex style. is there any library to do this in MFC?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could call TeX from the command line and insert the resulting image into your UI. Maybe there's an embeddable version of TeX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc from openoffice and save the formula like image. Then you can display it in your gui. I hope thet help you.